# Uploading an audiofile to server using Android Studio

Tags: php, android, audio, file-upload

Hi I'm struggling to upload an audio file which is saved on the phone to a server, in the below code I setDoOutput to true but it remains false. The error comes when I try new DataOutputStream, any idea why?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process:com.example.dialectdata, PID: 2296                                                             
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null,request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/audio:11464 flg=0x1 }} to activity{com.example.dialectdata/com.example.dialectdata.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

After running a debug it seems the error comes with the below code.
Here selectedPath is the file path on the phone, and urlString is the address to the php file. The

```
private void doFileUpload(){
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    DataInputStream inStream = null;
    String lineEnd = "rn";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary =  "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
    String responseFromServer = "";
    String urlString = "https://unintermitted-modul.000webhostapp.com/upload.php";
    try
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(selectedPath) );
        // open a URL connection to the Servlet
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Allow Outputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        // Don't use a cached copy.
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        // Use a post method.
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);
        dos = new DataOutputStream( conn.getOutputStream() );
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        // create a buffer of maximum size
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
        // read file and write it into form...
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }
        // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
        // close streams
        Log.e("Debug","File is written");
        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();
    }
```

Here is my PHP code on the server side.

```
    <?php   
    $target_path= "uploads/";  

   $target_path= $target_path. basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  

   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path)) 
   {  
       echo"The file ". basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']).  
       " has been uploaded";  
   }else{  
       echo"There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";  
       echo"filename: " .  basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);  
       echo"target_path: " .$target_path;  
   }  
   ?>
```

Thank you so much in advance.

The doFileUpload() is executed here:

```
   public void openGalleryAudio(){

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("audio/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);
}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        if (requestCode == SELECT_AUDIO)
        {
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO");
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedPath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            System.out.println("SELECT_AUDIO Path : " + selectedPath);
            doFileUpload();
        }
    }
}
```

openGalleryAudio() is executed when a button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it in AsyncTask:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>()
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        doFileUpload();
        return null;
    }
}.execute();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It states that the AsyncTask must be declared abstract or implement an abstract method when I put this piece of code into the program. I looked up the AsyncTask on the android developer page but just can't get my head around what that means, any ideas?

Comment: Could you post where you use your doFileUpload()?
Try to click on your AsyncTask, then Alt+Enter and implement required methods.

Comment: I have added the content of where it is used to the original post, I think it is executed correctly, I think the Async task goes in place where doFileUpload() is, but that doesnt seem right?

Comment: I implemented the methods and it seems okay, thanks for the help. The only remaining problem is in this statement where uploadedfile is not defined but I think that is a simple error                    
 dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadedfile";filename="" + selectedPath + """ + lineEnd);

Comment: You just forgot the concatenation.
Replace uploadedfile to +uploadedfile+

Answer (score 0):

Try Async :

```
private class FileUploadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        // File upload starts here
        doFileUpload();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Do whatever you wanna do after file upload finish
    }
}
```

Call the async from your Activity, Fragment, Service as following:-

```
FileUploadTask fileUploadTask = new FileUploadTask();
fileUploadTask.execute();
```